# How to find MySQL database in AWS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

This may sound like a silly question, but my client had me working on a dev version of his website, and now wants me to push changes to the live AWS server.

He's given me access, however I can't for the life of me find the MySQL database in AWS. I am given to understand it should be located under RDS but there seems to be nothing there:

[image]

Can someone tell me where to find it then? Did the client send me to the wrong server or something? He is not technical at all so not of any help.

Comment: Definitely no database there! He may have installed a LAMP stack and be running MySQL on his EC2 instance instead? Or perhaps you're looking in the wrong region?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tag editor to find all the resources that are running in the aws account (which can be tagged). Go to the tag editor and then select all region and resources to see where the db is running. Maybe its running under some other region and you are looking in the wrong region. Hope that helps

[image: AWS Tag editor]